# Is there a Protocol Buffers binding for Codegear C++ Builder 2007?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, c++builder, c++builder-2007

From my understanding reading this thread from several years ago, somebody once got Protocol Buffers working with Codegear C++ Builder 2007

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/protobuf/YapO_DqFVvc

The author of the above Builder 2007 version of protobuf uploaded it to a 3rd party URL, however the link to it seems to be long dead, and judging by the discussion and the current state of Protocol Buffers 2.5.0 the fix/change has never been forked from protobuf or merged into the trunk.

**Updated:**
When using generated code from protoc.exe (2.5.0) for either of the example .proto files, C++ Builder 2007 complains about a multitude of problems, including "duplicate entries" for names in the google::internal namespace (such as `google::internal::kEmptyString`  - it also complains about the `std::hash` based containers and that `memset` is an unrecognised symbol.

Comment: What is the actual problem(s) are you having?  You provided this long description with no real details in it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've finally managed to fix the problem, sorry about the lack of detail in the original post.  Updated the OP and added my solution as the answer in case it's useful to anyone else in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me several days to arrive at a solution, but here's how I managed to get it working in Codegear 2007:

1. Obtain the C++ Builder version of protobuf https://github.com/saadware/protobuf-cppbuilder - this is based on 2.4.1, so it is a little outdated, but I would guess that it's possible to merge the C++ builder changes into 2.5.0 (or whatever the latest version is).   The C++ Builder version of protobuf is for Builder 2009, but it fixes various problems with `std::hash`, so it's a better starting point than Google's release.
2. Take a copy of the following `.cc` files in the `./src/google/protobuf` folder and change them to a `.cpp` extension.  There seems to be an issue with the `.cbproj` format which doesn't like `.cc`  (You will need to add all of these files into your Codegear 2007 .cbproj - these are the files required for libprotobuf-lite).

   ```
   extension_set.cpp
   generated_message_util.cpp
   message_lite.cpp
   repeated_field.cpp
   wire_format_lite.cpp
   stubs\common.cpp
   stubs\once.cpp
   io\coded_stream.cpp
   io\zero_copy_stream.cpp
   io\zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cpp
   ```
3. As per the thread by 'Dazza' use find-and-replace-in-files (e.g. Notepad++) to rename the google::internal namespace.   Note that a case-sensitive find/replace is required because there are occurrences where the name 'Internal' is used for other things.  For this step I followed Dazza's suggestion of changing it to `google::internals`.  (Note - this is both for the libprotobuf-lite and for the strings used to make the generated code)
4. In the generated code strings, search for all occurrences of `memset` and change them to `std::memset`  (This is primarily for the code generator lib; `libprotoc`.  If you don't do this, every time you re-generate your .proto bindings, C++ builder will be unable to identify `memset`.
5. Build protoc.exe using Visual Studio (I couldn't get Protoc.exe to build in Builder, but that shouldn't matter anyway, the code generator only needs to be built once)
6. Modify the example .proto files use the lite runtime; 
   `option optimise_for = LITE_RUNTIME`.  Note - reflection capabilities are not available with this option switched on.
7. Run `protoc.exe` on your .proto file with `--cpp_out`.   The output file will have a `.cc` extension - you will need to rename this to `.cpp`
8. Add your generated files to your project and build.

(Note- there are still a few warnings outstanding - one complaining about a superfluous `&` taking the address of a function, and a few others complaining about signed/unsigned comparisons - but at least it builds and seems to work)